# How does 'line-height' in ems get calculated in this scenario?

Tags: css

I understand the line height is a multiple of the base font i.e. a paragraph with a font of 12px, and a line height of 2em will make it 24px.

I have some markup that is being copied from Word and pasted into a online rich text editor we have in our app.  In addition to tons of other garbage, we get the following scenario.  Sometimes text will get pasted with a span inside a paragraph, sometimes just the span. And each tag may have a different font size. (Totally up to word, we have no control). Regardless, the line heights need to be the same. But the example with the paragraph has a different line height, because the `<p>` tag has a bigger font size than the span.  Basically it appears `line-height` is calculated using the font size from the paragraph, but the font-size itself is from the span as you would expect.

My first question is... why does line height use the paragraph's font size instead of the span's?

My second is, can anyone think of a way around this using CSS?

Obviously you would just remove the inline styles, but the users of this app are not developers, they have no knowledge of html.  The point of this editor is for the users to create these online documents with no help from the devs.  I would love to find a way to overcome this in the style sheet.

```css
span, p {
   line-height: 2em;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<p style='font-size: 16px;'><span style="font-size: 12px;">Candidates will be given a hypothetical psychological report in which relevant background information (i.e., country of origin, primary language spoken in the home, and length of time living in the U.S.) and assessment data will be detailed.Candidates should demonstrate an increasing understanding and knowledge of CLD concepts and issues within the reports. Based on information provided candidates are to complete the report incorporating the following:</span>
</p>
<span style="font-size: 12px;">Candidates will be given a hypothetical psychological report in which relevant background information (i.e., country of origin, primary language spoken in the home, and length of time living in the U.S.) and assessment data will be detailed.Candidates should demonstrate an increasing understanding and knowledge of CLD concepts and issues within the reports. Based on information provided candidates are to complete the report incorporating the following:</span>
```

Comment: to your first question: your paragraph has also a line-height. don't forget that. so if you set `p { line-height: normal; }` your text should look ok. but i don't see any possibility to do this with css only as long as css4 pseudo attribute `:has` doesn't work in major browsers.

Comment: If the line heights all need to be a specific size, why not just use a specific size? ie: `line-height: 16px;`

Comment: @BlakeMann Because its not unusual for them to change their font size, so if they made it 22px, a 16px line height would be too small.  Unfortunately.

Comment: @Huelfe Because there may be paragraphs elsewhere in the document that need the same line height.  I really just don't understand why the paragraph takes precedence for line height but not other properties.  Killin me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `span` is inline and thus its text is affected by the surrounding line height (*that of the `p`*). If you set the `span` to `display:inline-block` it will be the same.

```css
span, p {
   line-height: 2em;
   font-size: 14px;
}
p span{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<p style='font-size: 16px;'><span style="font-size: 12px;">Candidates will be given a hypothetical psychological report in which relevant background information (i.e., country of origin, primary language spoken in the home, and length of time living in the U.S.) and assessment data will be detailed.Candidates should demonstrate an increasing understanding and knowledge of CLD concepts and issues within the reports. Based on information provided candidates are to complete the report incorporating the following:</span>
</p>
<span style="font-size: 12px;">Candidates will be given a hypothetical psychological report in which relevant background information (i.e., country of origin, primary language spoken in the home, and length of time living in the U.S.) and assessment data will be detailed.Candidates should demonstrate an increasing understanding and knowledge of CLD concepts and issues within the reports. Based on information provided candidates are to complete the report incorporating the following:</span>
```

Comment: That sheds some light on it for me, and technically answers the questions.  Unfortunately that won't help me though, because there will be spans that need to stay inline.  Thanks for the info tho.